# GA4 Traffic Going to Unassigned Page Path

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm looking at my web traffic from yesterday and I'm seeing that all the traffic to my usual page paths dropped to 0 and all traffic has gone to an undefined page path. Is there an explanation as to what is happening here?

[image]